# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream Error calling Azure Function HTTP Trigger

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have .NET Web App calling an HTTP Trigger Function App. But is returning below exception.
I have tried different combination of setting the SecurityProtocol but nothing works

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

The Web App is .NET Framework 4.8

FunctionApp is .NET Core 3.1

In what other areas should I check?

"An error occurred while sending the request.","InnerException":{"Status":"SendFailure","Response":null,"Data":[],"Message":"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.","InnerException":{"Data":[],"Message":"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.","InnerException":null,"TargetSite":"Void EndWrite(System.IAsyncResult)","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)","HelpLink":null,"Source":"System","HResult":-2146232800},"TargetSite":"System.IO.Stream EndGetRequestStream(System.IAsyncResult, System.Net.TransportContext ByRef)","StackTrace":"   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)","HelpLink":null,"Source":"System","HResult":-2146233079},"TargetSite":"Void Throw()","StackTrace":"   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at VisualRisk.ThirdPartyIntegration.GTreasury.Helpers.HttpHelper.d__16.MoveNext() in

Comment: Hello @Daniel, did you found any way to fix it ?